# .htaccess (mod_rewrite) 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this in my .htaccess
But i get 500 Internal Server Error.
I tried almost everything that i found in internet
for mod_rewrite, but it still doesn't helps me.
How do i fix this?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^zip/([A-Z]*)/([a-zA-Z]*)$ zip.php?state=$1&city=$2 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>

ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

FileETag MTime Size

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    <filesmatch ".(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|css|js|woff)$">
    ExpiresActive on
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"
    </filesmatch>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Have you tried checking your error logs or commenting out all lines and commenting in one by one to narrow down your problem?

Comment: /var/log/apache2/error.log is where you want to start...

Comment: I don't have access to apache error logs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try surrounding all your mod_rewrite directives in an ifmodule container:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^zip/([A-Z]*)/([a-zA-Z]*)$ zip.php?state=$1&city=$2 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

If that fixes it, then you know you don't have mod_rewrite loaded. Otherwise, time to remove lines out of your htaccess file until you stop getting the 500 error.

Comment: I have mod_rewrite enabled, so your code didn't helped me :P

Comment: @DandoZ900 start removing lines from your htaccess file until it's blank. Without access to your error logs, you have to blindly guess, if you still get the 500 with no htaccess file, then you know it's something else.

Answer (score 0):

There is issue with you mod_deflate.c
Make sure the deflate module is enabled. You can remove  to make it work as shown below.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^zip/([A-Z]*)/([a-zA-Z]*)$ zip.php?state=$1&city=$2 [L,QSA]

ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

FileETag MTime Size

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    <filesmatch ".(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|css|js|woff)$">
    ExpiresActive on
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"
    </filesmatch>
</IfModule>
```